# Why does google chrome need so many ports open?

Tags: google-chrome, port

[image]

I just did a port check with CPorts and I find that google chrome has so many local ports open in the range of 7713 - 7794. They are all connects to 80 or 443 on the other end.

Why does google chrome need all these ports?

Comment: Those aren't local ports that are open. Those are connections that are established.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Semantics.... there's no server on his machine listening at those ports, but they are apparently open since they can receive traffic from the host server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are the local port numbers of the sockets connected to the servers that host the websites you're browsing right now.

In TCP/UDP socket communication, there is always a **port** associated with a socket. For both the receiving and the sending side.

HTTP most commonly uses port 80. 443 is most commonly used by HTTPS.

The local port numbers have no real relevance or meaning. It's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Since Chrome 26 the build-in **asynchronous DNS** is enabled per default. This requires *several dozen* of additional UDP ports to be open. However, I have not found any documentation as to why in the world asynchronous DNS needs that many open ports. Do you have a clue?

Comment: @gentmatt: I'm not aware that it requires any additional open ports. Unless you're referring to outbound connections. Either way, you might want to [ask a new question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) about it.

Comment: There is already a very similar question to my problem at http://superuser.com/questions/567490/268-ports-associated-with-chrome/576161#576161 It's not so distict that I would require a new question. (Instead, I edited the answer in an attempt to bump the question to receive more attention.) I'm very confident that the open ports are linked to Google Chrome as I use a custom firewall to monitor network connections. The firewall reported all the requests to open additional ports after the latest Chrome 26 update.

Comment: If I disable asynchronous dns, remove the new port rules, and then restart Chrome, the firewall no longer requests to open all these additional ports.

Comment: @gentmatt: I also just updated, my firewall is not showing any additional open listening ports, neither does `netstat`. Maybe there's more to it. I would appreciate if you joined us in [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118/root-access). Maybe we can analyze this better in chat :)

Comment: @king_julien Depending on the exact design of the code it may be simpler to have a separate open UDP port per DNS request. But the protocol does allow for multiple ongoing requests from the same port number, so a different design with only one listening UDP port would have been possible.

Comment: But he's only got three tabs open. What are all the others?

Comment: a downvoted this answer, beacaus it is something to worry about. See my answer.

Answer (score -2):

This question is old, but still no statisfying answer.
Why does a browser need more than Port 80 or 443 ??

A browser doesn't need it but Google needs... for their ads:

https://www.xda-developers.com/fix-dns-ad-blocker-chrome/

DNS-based Ad Blockers are broken on latest Chrome versions.
You can find a fix there too.

https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/disable-async-dns-resolver-in-google-chrome/9500

Comment: I downvoted this answer because you misunderstood the question and you're confusing remote and local ports. If you want to complain about outgoing connections in Chrome, this is not the place.