# 268 Ports Associated with Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, port

I'm currently using a Windows box, running Chrome 27 on the dev channel, and I have what I believe to be an unusually large number of listening connections connected with the process.

The following command returns 268 listening ports:
`netstat -aon|find /i /c "11692"`
<sub>(*where in this case 11692 is the main chrome process*)</sub>


This is what some of the ports looks like from netstat:

```
UDP    0.0.0.0:62483          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62486          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62487          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62488          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62489          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62492          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62493          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62494          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62495          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62496          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62498          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62499          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62500          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62501          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62502          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62503          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62504          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62505          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62506          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62509          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62510          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62511          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62512          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62513          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62541          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62542          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62543          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62544          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62545          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62547          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62786          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62787          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62789          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62790          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62791          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62792          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62793          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62794          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62796          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62797          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62798          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62799          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62800          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62801          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62802          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62803          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62805          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62806          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62807          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62808          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62809          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62810          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62812          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62813          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62814          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62815          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62817          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62818          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62820          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62821          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62822          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62823          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62824          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62825          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62826          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62827          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62828          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62829          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:62830          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:64681          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:64682          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:64683          :                                    11692
UDP    0.0.0.0:65017          :                                    11692
```

Maybe I'm missing something with my reading of netstat, but this seems unusually high.

This is a repeat issue.  The only thing needed to evoke the massive number of ports listening is to start Chrome.  Also, when I close Chrome, always at least one process is still running after I close the browser, and seems to run indefinitely (*this is not the process associated with the large number of ports open - or at least not by itself - as the ports go away when I close the browser*).

Does anyone know:

1. If this is normal?
2. If it's not normal, what could explain it?
3. How I could find out more information about what is actually going on?

I have Wireshark installed, but it always seems to confound my understanding, and I haven't felt like trying to grok it yet.  Also, Windows Event Log reveals nothing.

Note that this is not a duplicate of question [Why does Google need so many ports open?](https://superuser.com/questions/409531/why-does-google-chrome-need-so-many-ports-open) as these ports are not dedicated to - and do not appear to be related to - any websites at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've messed with your experimental settings... that's why!
Check chrome://flags/ and tell me if "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" is Enabled or Default/Disabled... it should be Default.

Comment: Nice!  I think you are absolutely right.  I had messed with some flags, though I can't remember whether that was one of them.  However, after a regular chrome version update, this stopped happening.  Maybe that flag reverts after update - it is on default now.  Other flags I've set didn't revert.  Anyway - thanks for helping remove the mysterious nature of the issue:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Asynchronous DNS** on Chrome, read more about it at [The Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/dns-prefetching)

Long story short: Chrome uses native Windows synchronous DNS resolutions by default, which means it has to wait for every resolution successively, regardless of how many tabs are concurrently loading, which will add a noticeable lag to their loading depending on the order they resolve new hosts. A proposed solution was to make this component asynchronous, for this Chrome needed to bypass the native DNS component of Windows, add one of its own, and thus open a few more UDP ports when needed.

That behaviour, in the top question, is due to the component being in development stage and thus will appear so, have many connections, being unrestricted and a resource waster. This was happening only if the user manually changed a flag in Chrome to activate this feature, usually reserved for developers or contributors. See "Obsolete answer" for an explanation on how to access on older versions of Chrome.

For the newer versions of Chrome, I can say for v43, this behaviour has been fixed, and now it uses fewer UDP ports depending on the number of unknown hosts it needs to resolve, otherwise it will use cached resolutions and have fewer opened ports.

As far as I can tell, current versions of Chrome don't have a flag for enabling it, it does exist and can be enabled through a switch on chrome.exe. **By default, it's disabled**.

Edit Chrome's shortcuts and add *--enable-async-dns* after the *chrome.exe"* target, separate them through a space. In Windows 7, for a pinned shortcut, right click the pin, in the tile menu right click the Google Chrome shortcut above the *Unpin this program...* option and access its properties, edit the Target there.

To find out if Asynchronous DNS is enabled, access *chrome://net-internals/#dns* and there should be a listing called *Internal DNS client enabled: true* or *false*

Obsolete answer (option exists in older versions, around 27):

Enter this in the address bar of Google Chrome:

```
chrome://flags/
```

Scroll down the list and make sure "**Built-in Asynchronous DNS**" is Disabled.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please add some more details for somebody not in the know. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Comment: @vonbrand: I don't think he's the question asker. By "I should have posted this as an answer" looks like he was referring to his previous comment above, which seems to have solved the issue. What I don't understand is, why didn't he use the same username and password he had already registered with, instead of creating a new user with the same name?

Comment: @Karan, the email got somewhat malformed when I registered, and I could not access that account anymore. I've experimented with some password lockers and one made me some issues, it's not the only case when I typed my email and it got rewritten... thus I made a new account.

Comment: Build-in asynchronous DNS is enabled per default ever since Chrome 26. Since I use a custom firewall, I was able to see all these port connections pop up after the Chrome update. However, I have not found any documentation as to why in the world asynchronous DNS wants to open up **several dozen** new ports. Do you have a clue?

Comment: Thanks...I just got that you were the same person who posted the comment and have accepted your answer.

Comment: @gentmatt, actually it's not, I have it default at 26 and there are no UDP ports open, but that might also be residual settings after upgrading. Enabled it, 511 UDP ports open now, they said only 8 threads will be used for resolving host names. Maybe this preallocation is a speed fix, a way to cut back on the lag hit when UDP ports are allocated on request. Each request falls on the OS to find available ports and give them to the app when needed, but instead of wasting time on this, Chrome keeps them allocated so it cuts back on some time loss. Anything other than that... can only be a bug.

Comment: @king_julien, Hmm, because asynchronous means concurrent so you need to have multiple connections. If you have synchronous connection, one connection is needed but they would only be able to do requests one-at-a-time. Does that make sense?  Note that I'm guessing.

Comment: @JasonXA, Please edit the question. Explain what is this "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" you're talking about and How does it work?